# android edittext limit to text and numbers

Tags: android, xml, text, numbers, android-edittext

I am creating an android application.  The first thing I'm creating is a login activity.  I am trying to limit the username edittext just to text/numbers only (no special characters).  Is there a way to adjust this in the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can limit the characters from xml. You could always use a InputFilter, but specifically android provides [UsernameFilterGeneric](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/LoginFilter.UsernameFilterGeneric.html) to filter valid user names. You could also use [UsernameFilterGMail](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/LoginFilter.UsernameFilterGMail.html)

Comment: so there's no way I can specify the inputType for an edittext to be text/numbers only?

Comment: If you want through Inputtype, then i dont think you can do.  You can always override LoginFilter. You just need to implement isAllowed function. Just return true for all the characters you think you want to allow

Answer (score 0):

As you already use in java Regular expression.called the same class here for checking for particular field.
let me know if you want some more if you didn't know about the RE.

Comment: can I do this in the xml for inputType?

Comment: you have two option.
1)use this at time of execution of program at run time in java file
2)xml : use the input type method and in style give the particular validation of your choice.

Comment: so for clarification, I can do RE for text/numbers as the inputType?